# get controls id for buttons under a ribbon in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Hi Friends can any one tell me how to get the control id for the controls in the ribbon bar for sharepoint 2010 so that I can enable or disable them.

Answer (score 0):

I would try either [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) or TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.XML in the 14 hive.

Answer (score 0):

When u create custom ribbon you have ID attribute in Button tag.

```
<Button Id="Ribbon.yourid">
```

so give it id you wan't to like and find tag using jquery

```
$("[id^='Ribbon.yourid']")
```